# Use code to disable player input unreal engine

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I have seen a lot of ways to use the node based visual scripts to stop player input; However, I have not seen a single example of how to disable the player input in visual studio?

Comment: You should ask this question over at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ , where there is greater Unreal expertise and people will know what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable player input using the function:

`AActor::DisableInput(APlayerController* PlayerController)`

This should be called on the actor you wish to disable input for. You need to have a pointer to the current player controller, and pass this as the function's argument. You can easily get the first (and usually *only*, in single player game) player controller from the current world:

`UWorld::GetFirstPlayerController();`

Quick example, with `PlayerPawn` being a pointer to the AActor that you wish to disable input for:

```
APlayerController* PlayerController = GetWorld()->GetFirstPlayerController();
PlayerPawn->DisableInput(PlayerController);
```